# How to direct directory from file to another on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, directory

So I am currently trying to install python3 into my Mac and whenever I type in

```
which python3
```

It gives me the response of

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

However, I want it to point to this directory below:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_2/bin/python3
```

How do I make this happen? Please Help!!

Comment: You probably have that already. On my mac, `/usr/local/bin/python3` is a symlink: `/usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python3/3.5.1/bin/python3`. Check it with `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3`. You did install python using brew, right?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thank you. And yes I did install python with brew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install `python` with brew, it will actually create a symlink from `/usr/loca/bin/...` to `/usr/loca/Cellar/...`. You can check this for example by running this command:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mfischer  admin  35  3 Aug 07:34 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python3/3.5.1/bin/python3
```

If this is not the case, simply recreate the link.

```
rm /usr/local/bin/python3
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_2/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python3
```

Comment: Thank you!! I'm fairly new to this whole thing and hardly have any idea what is going on